# How to treat string as UTC timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I have to read strings like '20190608070000' as timestamps given in UTC. Is there an easy way to do that?

This one takes UTC but needs formatted input:

```sql
postgres=# show time zone;
 TimeZone
----------
 CET
(1 Zeile)

postgres=# select timestamp without time zone '2019-06-08 07:00:00' at time zone 'UTC';
        timezone
------------------------
 2019-06-08 09:00:00+02
(1 Zeile)
```

Whereas to_timestamp() invariably treats all input as local time as far as I see, so the output is shifted the wrong way:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT to_timestamp('20190608070000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') AT time zone 'UTC';
      timezone
---------------------
 2019-06-08 05:00:00
(1 Zeile)
```

Actually I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of [`TO_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-formatting.html) is `timestamp with time zone`. The time shown is in your current session's time zone(with the UTC offset).

```
SET SESSION timezone TO 'CET';
SET
knayak=# SELECT to_timestamp('20190608070000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
      to_timestamp
------------------------
 2019-06-08 07:00:00+02
```

When you transform it with `AT TIME ZONE`, it will show the time in UTC when it's `07:00` hours in your current time zone.

```
SELECT to_timestamp('20190608070000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') AT time zone 'UTC';
      timezone
---------------------
 2019-06-08 05:00:00
(1 row)
```

So, If you wish to read your timestamp in a desired format and treat that as UTC, cast the output of `to_timestamp` explicitly to `timestamp` (without time zone) and then apply `AT TIME ZONE`.

```
SELECT to_timestamp('20190608070000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') :: timestamp 
    AT time zone 'UTC';

        timezone
------------------------
 2019-06-08 09:00:00+02
(1 row)
```

Comment: I have been so close ... Thank you!